# Algorithm for resolving conflicts with overlapping choices

Tags: python, algorithm, constraint-programming

I have a computational problem where I have a set of tags that can be given away exactly once, and a number of items that each have a set of possible choices of tags that they can accept. I need to assign the tags in such a way that each item gets a tag whenever there is a solution to the problem.

To give a specific example, if I had a dictionary like this:

```
options = {
  'a': [1],
  'b': [2, 3],
  'c': [1, 2]
}
```

..then the solution would be:

```
 {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}
```

I will also need to be able to expand the problem to handle multiple constraints, e.g.

```
[1], ['A', 'B']         # -> (1, A) or (1, B)
[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'C']   # -> (3, C)
[1, 2], ['A', 'C']      # -> (2, A) or (2, B)
```

I have tried to come up with workable solutions based on a priority queue for the simple case, but that completely falls apart with multiple constraints. I could brute-force a solution using `itertools.permutations`, but I'd prefer an efficient implementation. Is there any known algorithm that might be applicable to this problem?

Comment: What if there are multiple solutions, like if you had options = {'a': [1,2],'b': [2, 3],'c': [1, 2]), is the solution then {'a': [1,2], 'b': 3, 'c': [1,2]} or do you want to get a set of all solutions?

Comment: Just one solution. The scope of this question is to avoid incomplete solutions rather than enumerate all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, what you have in the example is a simple constraint satisfaction problem with three variables `['a', 'b', 'c']`, each with a finite domain of integers and the "all-distinct" constraint.

Backtracking search with appropriate heuristics can solve this type of problems fairly quickly in practice. E.g.

```
def backtracking(domains):
    if any(len(dom) == 0 for var, dom in domains.iteritems()):
        return None
    if all(len(dom) == 1 for var, dom in domains.iteritems()):
        return domains

    # minimum remaining values heuristic: process variables with few possible
    # values first (fail-first strategy)
    order = sorted(domains.iteritems(), key=lambda (var, dom): len(dom))
    for var, dom in order:
        if len(dom) == 1:
            continue

        for value in list(dom):
            doms = {v: d - {value} for v, d in domains.iteritems()
                                   if v != var}
            doms[var] = {value}

            solution = backtracking(doms)
            if solution is not None:
                return solution

print(backtracking({v: set(d) for v, d in options.iteritems()}))
```

Comment: This certainly looks like it is going to work for the simple case and I am confident that it could be expanded to the complex case, if at a higher cost.

Comment: Just some comments after looking at the solution in more detail: This solution fails if the original case already has a failure state, e.g. if `options = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': [3]}`. Otherwise the solution can easily be extended by changing `d - {value}` (_aka the reject step_) to whatever is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use backtracking to resolve this problem.
Depending on the constraints if a greedy algorithm can be implementing, choosing 1 tag at a time to achieve global optimum

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to implement a whole backtracking system just to resolve this problem. Many researchers already built systems and modelling languages to facilitate this kind of problem solving.

Your problem is a very classic Constraint Satisfaction Problem where we have the AllDifferent Constraint. I propose to you to use a high level modelling language like minizinc (http://www.minizinc.org/) and you'll see by yourself the difference. Here a simple model (for your problem) written in this format :

```
include "globals.mzn";
var {1} : a;
var {2,3} : b;
var {1,2} : c;
constraint alldifferent([a,b,c]);

solve  satisfy;

output ["a :  ", show(a), "\n" ,
        "b :  ", show(b), "\n" ,
        "c :  ", show(c), "\n" ];
```

If this is your first time using minizinc, you can start with the latest tutorial [here](http://www.minizinc.org/downloads/doc-latest/minizinc-tute.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It is really a very basic AllDifferent Constraint. If interested in python, using 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-constraint

```
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("a", [1, 2])
problem.addVariable( "b", [2, 3])
problem.addVariable("c", [1, 2])
problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint())
print problem.getSolution()
```

(will give you first one found if exists
or

```
print sorted(sorted(x.items()) for x in problem.getSolutions())
```

will give all solutions)